# cellForItemAtIndexPath never called

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` that I added to my `UIViewController` in my Storyboard.

It contains a `UICollectionViewCell` of class `BookCell` and reusable identifier `BookCell`.

`bookArray` gets passed in the `prepareForSegue` method from the previous ViewController

`cellForItemAtIndexPath` never gets called. I have attempted to declare  `BookCollectionVC` as delegate and dataSource both in Storyboard and in `viewDidLoad`, as you can see commented out, but that does not change anything.

I have read multiple SO answers pertaining to cell size, to the number of items in the section, to the multiple ways of declaring `delegate` and `dataSource` and have tried/double checked all of them.

Any ideas?

```
class BookCollectionVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet weak var collection: UICollectionView!

    var bookArray = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//        collection.delegate = self
//        collection.dataSource = self
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("BookCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? BookCell {

            // This never gets called
            let bookIsbn = bookArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(bookIsbn)
            return cell

        } else {

            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
    } 

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(bookArray.count)
        return bookArray.count
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        let cellWidth = screenWidth / 4

        return CGSizeMake(cellWidth,cellWidth)
    }
```

Comment: can you please check the items into `bookArray` array ?

Comment: What do you mean check the items `into` ? @Dev

Comment: If there is no items into `bookArray` then `cellForItemAtIndexPath ` is never is going to call. In the sample code you assigned `bookArray` as empty array. You need to make sure that `bookArray` has some object in order to `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method is being executed.

Comment: Does the line return UICollectionViewCell() ever get called? Also have you registered the cell called BookCell?

Comment: He doesnt have to register it if it exists in the storyboard inside the collection view. As others asks, are u sure u have any items in ur array?

Comment: Yes, it gets passed from the previous viewController.  I can print it out in `viewDidLoad` and there are multiple items inside

Comment: Check the `itemSize` of `collectionViewFlowLayout`. If it is too big, `cellForItemAtIndexPath ` doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

As a test, don't use an if-let. Just get the cell value and print it. What is its type? Have you properly assigned the cells to be the custom class (BookCell) in your StoryBoard?